# how to check a folder already exists before extracting from zip file to a specific location?

Tags: php

```
$zipfile = 'zipfilename';
$extractpath= 'C:\extract';

$zip = new ZipArchive();  

if ($zip->open($zipfile) !== TRUE) {
   die ("Could not open archive");
}
// extract contents to destination directory
$zip->extractTo($extractpath);
```

How to avoid overwriting a folder if it already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$extractpath = '/somewhere/someplace/';
if (is_dir($extractpath) AND file_exists($extractpath)) {
   // Path exists
}
```

#### Update

> Actually I want to avoid overwriting a folder while unzipping?

AFAIK, you can't *overwrite* a folder. But you can overwrite a file. To see if the destination file already exists, use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) (using with [`is_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) is probably wise as well).

Comment: @Jacob Relkin Well if the path is `/somewhere/someplace` and a `someplace` file exists, `file_exists()` will return `TRUE` :)

Comment: @alex, Okay makes sense. But then why would `is_dir` return true?

Comment: actually i want to avoid overwriting a folder while unzipping??

Comment: @Jacob Relkin I just tested it with `var_dump(file_exists(rtrim(APPPATH, '/')));` in a Kohana installation. It returned `TRUE` :)

Comment: @alex That's so *weird*. But then again, I'm not surprised. PHP is one really effed up language.

Comment: Oh, and `var_dump(is_dir(rtrim(APPPATH, '/')));` returns `TRUE` as well :)

Comment: hi my situation is some like this i dont want to unzipt if a  a folder with the same name already exist